# Font personalizado en menu ListView dinámico - Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, fuentes

Tengo un `ListView` vacío donde sus `Items / Views` se crean de forma dinámica desde código de la siguiente forma:

```
MenuTexto = new string[]
                {
                    "Noticias", "  Ver titulares", 
                    "Preferencias", "  Cambiar foto de perfil", "  Pais",
                    "Contactanos",
                    "Cerrar sesion"
                };

            MenuImagenes = new int[]
            {
                Resource.Mipmap.rfnews2, Resource.Mipmap.rfblanco,
                Resource.Mipmap.rfcine, Resource.Mipmap.rfblanco, Resource.Mipmap.rfblanco, 
                Resource.Mipmap.rfcorreo2,
                Resource.Mipmap.rfoff2
            };

            if (objAdapterMenu != null)
            {
                objAdapterMenu.actionMenuSelected -= ConfiguracionDeBotones;
                objAdapterMenu = null;
            }
            objAdapterMenu = new MenuListAdapterClass3(this, MenuTexto, MenuImagenes);
            objAdapterMenu.actionMenuSelected += ConfiguracionDeBotones;
            menuListView.Adapter = objAdapterMenu;
```

Funciona excelente, el problema es que necesito poder cambiar el `Font / TypeFace` y no logro hacerlo.

De los TextViews normales lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
TextView Lbl = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.LblTitulo);
                tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "quicks.ttf"); 
                Lbl.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

Comment: Si tienes un adaptador, asumo que tienes una vista personalizada, ¿Puedes mostrarla?

Comment: No sabia que era la "vista personalizada" a la que te referías pero justamente lei tu comentario acabando de leer este articulo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927366/set-custom-font-to-spinner (que por si solo tampoco había entendido por completo), pero al estar buscando en el adaptador que cosa podia ser la "vista personalizada" encontré el GetView, así que ya pude hacerlo.

Muchas gracias. Pondré la respuesta completa en unos momentos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue asignar el `font` personalizado desde el adaptador del Menu, precisamente en el método `GetView`, quedando el `adapter` de la siguiente forma:

```
#region "Menu list adapter"
    public class MenuListAdapterClass3 : BaseAdapter<string>
    {


        Activity _context;
        string[] _mnuText;
        int[] _mnuUrl;
        internal event Action<string> actionMenuSelected;
        public MenuListAdapterClass3(Activity context, string[] strMnu, int[] intImage)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mnuText = strMnu;
            _mnuUrl = intImage;
        }
        public override string this[int position]
        {
            get { return this._mnuText[position]; }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return this._mnuText.Count(); }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            MenuListViewHolderClass3 objMenuListViewHolderClass3;
            View view;
            view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MenuLayout, parent, false);
                objMenuListViewHolderClass3 = new MenuListViewHolderClass3();

                objMenuListViewHolderClass3.txtMnuText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtMnuText);
                objMenuListViewHolderClass3.ivMenuImg = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivMenuImg);

                objMenuListViewHolderClass3.initialize(view);
                view.Tag = objMenuListViewHolderClass3;
            }
            else
            {
                objMenuListViewHolderClass3 = (MenuListViewHolderClass3)view.Tag;
            }

            **// Asignacion de Font personalizada a Menu:
            Typeface typeFace1 = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "quicks.ttf");
            objMenuListViewHolderClass3.txtMnuText.SetTypeface(typeFace1, TypefaceStyle.Bold);**

            objMenuListViewHolderClass3.viewClicked = () =>
            {
                if (actionMenuSelected != null)
                {
                    actionMenuSelected(_mnuText[position]);
                }
            };
            objMenuListViewHolderClass3.txtMnuText.Text = _mnuText[position];
            objMenuListViewHolderClass3.ivMenuImg.SetImageResource(_mnuUrl[position]);
            return view;
        }

    }
    internal class MenuListViewHolderClass3 : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        internal Action viewClicked { get; set; }
        internal TextView txtMnuText;
        internal ImageView ivMenuImg;
        public void initialize(View view)
        {
            view.Click += delegate
            {
                viewClicked();
            };
        }

    }

    #endregion
```